# Cannot login into SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

I foolishly and accidently deleted windows admin from SQL Server 2008 Logins. Now I cannot connect to Sql Server Management Studio. Why is it even possible to delete this login if you cannot login to sql server afterwards ?

I have admin right to this box.

Please advsise before I kill myself for being so stupid :)

Comment: If you change the hostname, Sql Server will keep your login under the old hostname, but Windows will be using the new hostname. That's one reason why you might want to delete yourself.

The other thing is: it is very difficult to delete the windows admin from Sql Server because that admin normally owns all sorts of things, like databases. So you will have to change lots of things before SSMS lets you delete that Login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you removed the #1 Windows user or the #2 'sa' user?

In #1, you can use 'sa', if you just remember the password you've given at installation. Or you can create a new admin user to Windows and use Windows Authentication with that user login.

In #2 I think it's more difficult, if you have not allowed Windows authentication (I don't remember if you can leave it out, though)

Edit: A quick Google search gave this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Comment: My case is #1, I have another windows account, but I cannot connect to SQL Server with it, and I cannot change sa password. I logged in using Domain\SQLEXPRESS, but I cannot add the windows login since it says I don't have enough privileges

Comment: Check the link I found, if it works with SQL Server 2008 as well